# Есть список, который стал словарем, как сделать чтобы строчные ключи были в нижнем или верхнем регистре

Tags: python-3.x

```
from collections import Counter
array = [5, 1, 2, '4', 'Ate', 'Ab', 'aa']
a = Counter(array)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Counter(x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in array)
```

Comment: спасибо, никогда не додумался, делал так, a = Counter(array)
for k, v in a.items():
        if a.items() == str:
            a[k.upper()] = a.pop(k).upper()